# How do I perform an ActiveRecord query after form submission?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Would this work? I want to do something like coins transfer

```
@logs = Logs.new(log_params)
@logs.save
@tt = Users.where(email: params[:email]).update(money: Users.find(current_user.id)['money'] - params[:money])
@tt.save
@wr = Users.find(current_user.id).update(money: Users.where(email: params[:email])['money'] + params[:money])
@wr.save
```

Comment: I recommend wrapping that in a transaction and use a solid validation service for your money object. Don't simply pass `params[:money]`. Don't mess with $$$ ^^.

Comment: Even better, you could create a MoneyTransfer model to keep track of transactions. The balance would be a snapshot after all transactions are applied. Things might get messy otherwise.

Comment: thank you , it's was really helpfull

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you are planning to display those values in your views, but you could do something like this:

```
sender = Users.where(email: params[:email]).first
# This returns the user
recipient = Users.find(current_user.id) 
# or just current_user if it inherit from the User class
money_to_substract = recipient.money - params[:money]
money_to_sum = recipient.money + params[:money]
```

Then your transsaction would be a bit *dryier*

```
User.transaction do
  @logs = Logs.new(log_params)
  @tt = sender.update(money: money_to_substract)
  # update saves to the database so no need to call save
  # @tt.save
  @wr = recipient.update(money: money_to_sum)
  # update saves to the database so no need to call save
  # @wr.save
end
```

But IMHO, I would do something like this:

*models/User.rb*

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  ...

  def sends_money(amount)
    money_to_substract = self.money - amount
    update(money: money_to_substract)
  end

  def receives_money(amount)
    money_to_sum = self.money + amount
    update(money: money_to_sum)
  end

  ...

end
```

In your controller

```
amount = params[:money].to_i
User.transaction do
  @logs = Logs.new(log_params)
  @tt = sender.sends_money(amount)
  @wr = recipient.receives_money(amount)
end
```

Which makes things easier to read and follow through your code.

Hope this helps!

Comment: @Fluffy, could you try any of the above?